# Why is this derivative incorrect?

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

We have to find the derivative of $$f(x) = \dfrac{\tan(2x)}{\sin(x)}$$

I would like to know why my approach is incorrect:

$$f'(x) = \dfrac{\sin(x) \cdot \dfrac{2}{\cos^2(2x)}  - \tan(2x) \cdot \cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}$$

$$ =  \dfrac{ 2 \sin(x) - \tan(2x) \cdot \cos(x)}{\cos^2(2x) \cdot \sin^2(x)}$$

$$ = \dfrac {2 \sin(x) - \sin(2x) \cdot \cos(x)}{\cos^3(2x) \cdot \sin^2(x)}$$

p.s. - To avoid confusion ; I wanted to get rid of the $\tan$. I'm sure there is a shorter method than this but I don't want it; I just want to know why this is wrong.

Comment: You've incorrectly simplified across the second equals sign, as well as the third.  Be careful, $\frac{ab^{-1}-c}{d}\ne\frac{a-c}{bd}$.  Can you see why?

Comment: If you are seeking to remove a denominator in the numerator or denominator of a _compound fraction_, you need to multiply across the _entire_ numerator and denominator of that fraction by the factor you want to clear.  Here, "top and bottom" need to be multiplied by $ \ \cos^2 (2x) \ $ in going to line 2 , leading to the result Amire Bendjeddou shows.  ("Everybody" commits this oversight at one time or another...)

Comment: @Jared , RecklessReckoner thanks, that was the mistake I was 'looking for'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Third line is: $ \dfrac{ 2 \sin(x) - \tan(2x) \cdot \cos(x)\cdot\cos^2(2x)}{\cos^2(2x) \cdot \sin^2(x)}$ 
instead of $\\\\ \dfrac{ 2 \sin(x) - \tan(2x) \cdot \cos(x)}{\cos^2(2x) \cdot \sin^2(x)}$

Answer (score 2):

$$f'(x) = \dfrac{\sin(x) \cdot \dfrac{2}{\cos^2(2x)}  - \tan(2x) \cdot \cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}\tag{1}$$

So far so good...

But your following line is where you made an algebraic error: you forgot to multiply both (the *entire* numerator (both terms)) and (the denominator) by $\cos^2(2x)$. Doing this gives us:

$$f'(x) = \dfrac{\color{blue}{\bf \cos^2(2x)}\left(\sin(x) \cdot \dfrac{2}{\cos^2(2x)}  - \tan(2x) \cdot \cos(x)\right)}{\color{blue}{\bf \cos^2(2x)}\sin^2(x)}$$

NOW we distribute across the numerator, canceling the denominator of the first term, and multiplying the second term by $\cos^2{2x}$:

$$ =  \dfrac{2\sin(x) - \tan(2x) \cdot \cos(x)\cdot \cos^2(2x)}{\cos^2(2x)\sin^2(x)}\tag{2}$$
$$ = \dfrac{2\sin(x) - \sin(2x) \cdot \cos^2(2x)\cdot \cos(x)}{\cos^3(2x)\sin^2(x)}\tag{3}$$

Comment: Very nice use of color to make points +1 Today is a VERY slow day, but lots to do at work and prep for talk this Friday at work and talk next week. Hope you're having a great day (did you know they are trying to eliminate contractions)!